# call service references from xamarin forms c#

Tags: c#, json, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I did a web service amsx and put on a server.
I tried with postman and everything works.
Now here's the problem, I am creating an app Xamarin forms, and can not figure out how to recover data.

In series I did the following:

1

[image]

2

[image]

3

[image]

my problem is that I can not understand how you can call methods and return the json inside them and then deserialize with newsofton.json.
Can anyone give me a solution?

ps.: methods:

[image]

instance of WebServiceSoapClient have that methods:

[image]

**SOLUTION**

first call this:

```
ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient test = new WebServiceSoapClient();                
test.getUsersCompleted += Test_getUsersCompleted;
test.getUsersAsync();
```

and create method event:

```
 private void Test_getUsersCompleted(object sender, getUsersCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

**e** object have data from web service

Comment: Why are you trying to create an instance of event args?  According to the intellisense you need to provide that constructor with some values, do you have those values?  Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/asmx/

Comment: please DO NOT post code as images.  They're not searchable and are difficult to read. Take the time to post and format your code as text.

Comment: @David I'm trying to recall a all'intervno service reference method that returns me the return of the web service function, the web service returns to me the json data from a table sql.

Comment: Just subscribe to the `getUsersCompleted` event and call `getUsersAsync()`. WCF deals with the abstraction of serialization, you don't have to (de)serialize yourself: you'll only have to deal with objects.

Comment: i have added the image with WebServiceSoapClient, but the method getUsersAsync is void, why ? how to get json inside them ?

Comment: @CodeCaster getUserAsync return void...how to get the data ?

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: @CodeCaster 
I but I struggle to understand, maybe I'll be stubborn. If I call the event getUsersCompleted this makes me as a method where I have a void inside. And even if it takes me to the method gesUserAsync back to me void, however, why I do not understand.

Comment: thanks all the same, I can :) floor plan are new to this type of web service and are not very practical

Comment: See [MSDN: How to: Call WCF Service Operations Asynchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @CodeCaster I solved it, everything works. you can answer the question that you sign as the correct question if you want.

Comment: Nah, just post your answer as an answer instead of editing it into your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling a SOAP service which will more than likely be XML. This won't be using Newtonsoft json, and the approach you are using will hide the transfer of the string data. Actually, you should probably elaborate why you want to see the json data. But, if you really want to see the json, you should create a REST service (not SOAP) and you should call the service with a REST client.

This library has some samples for getting data via Newtonsoft
https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net